# Why image has different pixel resolution in Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, unity-ui

I'm working on application, where small `UI.Images` are displayed with small textures **32x32** pixels. It is very important to display each pixel properly.

When I'm trying to launch the application in Unity everything is perfect - Image consists of **32x32** pixels.

[image: Image in Unity]

While deployed to Hololens, the Image has worse quality and resolution changes to **16x16** pixels.

[image: Image in Hololens]

The question is how to obtain texture displayed in 32x32 pixels quality on Hololens device?

Comment: Erm, I realized a few minutes after editing that "Sprite" in the title wasn't referring to a picture of a soda can bearing that name.  It's the type of image.  Sorry!  I don't believe my edit was harmful, but if there is any disagreement, please feel free to revert.

Comment: Don't worry, I have tried to be as precise as I can, so I used the name of Sprite, but Image probably is also a correct one :)

Comment: I don't remember having this issue when I worked with the HoloLens a year ago, so I can't think of what the issue might be. :\

Comment: The pixel format might matter. Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I figured it out. In Unity *Edit > Project Settings > Quality* the option **Very Low** is used for Hololens application. In this mode the **Texture Quality** is set to **Half Res**, thus the *Image* was rendered with half of the pixels' number (16 pixels). When changed to **Full Res**, the *Image* get original 32 pixels size.

It does not explain why in Unity Editor the Image was displayed properly, but the most important thing is that now it's working properly on the device.